# IMO Longlist 1989 (Number of ways product can be expressed)

Tags: combinatorics

Given two distinct numbers $ b_1$ and $ b_2$, their product can be formed in two ways: $ b_1 \times b_2$ and $ b_2 \times b_1.$ Given three distinct numbers, $ b_1, b_2, b_3,$ their product can be formed in twelve ways:

$ b_1\times(b_2 \times b_3);$ $ (b_1 \times b_2) \times b_3;$ $ b_1 \times (b_3 \times b_2);$ $ (b_1 \times b_3) \times b_2;$  $ b_2 \times (b_1 \times b_3);$ $ (b_2 \times b_1) \times b_3;$ $ b_2 \times(b_3 \times b_1);$ $ (b_2 \times b_3)\times b_1;$ $ b_3 \times(b_1 \times b_2);$ $ (b_3 \times b_1)\times b_2;$ $ b_3 \times(b_2 \times b_1);$ $ (b_3 \times b_2) \times b_1.$

In how many ways can the product of $ n$ distinct letters be formed?

Comment: See with $3*2*1$ are you sure its 12 ways

Comment: How many numbers a bracket enclose? 2? Or $n-1$ number of numbers? And how many brackets are allowed?

Comment: @ArchisWelankar you missed the arrangement of brackets

Comment: Maybe it is easier to use reverse polish notation.

Comment: Wow, this was an IMO longlist problem? Things were different in 1989...

Answer (score 3):

There are $n!$ possible arrangements of the $n$ factors. For each of these arrangements, there are $C_{n-1}$ possible parenthesizations, where $C_k$ is the $k$-th [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number). We have
$$
C_k=\frac{1}{k+1}\binom{2k}{k}
$$
so the product of $n$ factors can be formed in
$$
n!C_{n-1}=\frac{n!}{n}\binom{2(n-1)}{n-1}=\frac{(2n-2)!}{(n-1)!}
$$ 
ways.